# An infinite atwood machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

Below is a seemingly simple problem involving an infinite system of pulleys.

> Consider the infinite Atwood’s machine shown below. A string passes
>   over each pulley, with one end attached to a mass and the other end
>   attached to another pulley. All the masses are equal to $m$, and all
>   the pulleys and strings are massless. The masses are held fixed and
>   then simultaneously released. What is the acceleration of the top
>   mass?
>
> [image: pulley system]
>
> (We’ll define this infinite system as follows. Consider it to be made
>   of $N$ pulleys, with a non-zero mass replacing what would have been the
>   $(N + 1)$st pulley. Then take the limit as $N\to\infty$.)

Comment: The reason tension is proportional to acceleration is because tension is a force, and $F=ma$. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: no, because there can be a resistive force, e.g. $T-mg= ma$ so $T=a(m-\frac{mg}{a}$).

Comment: -1. If you are asking about a difficulty understanding the linked solution, you need to identify (by page and paragraph) what part of that solution is causing difficulty.

Comment: Before tackling the Infinite Atwood Machine, you should make sure you are comfortable with the solutions to the Single Atwood Machine and Double Atwood Machine. See links on the right.

Comment: For recommendations of other sites see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the question is delightful. I did look at the solution but I didn't understand it too. So I came up with this one (maybe it resembles the standard solution, maybe not) .

See, if we create a similar pulley system in a smart way such that it would behave exactly the same like this one and see it working then we can easily get an answer.

To make such a system, you must agree that $$\infty + 1 = \infty$$

So if you exclude the first pulley, what remains is the same system of pulleys because if you take away one pulley from the system, that wont make a difference because there are an infinite number of them. This is what our  system will look like -

[image]

Now, what if we say that let us **suppose** that the tension in string $a$ is $mg$ . What will be its consequences?

Well, the first ball won’t move because on it the forces will be balanced. 
Because of this, the second pulley won’t move! **Due to this our system will completely behave as the system which is given in the question because the top pulley in the question is not able to move and the top pulley in our system will also not move.**

As the pulley’s are massless, the tension in $b$ will be $\frac{mg}{2}$ . Hence the net force on the first ball will be $ mg - \frac{mg}{2}   = \frac{mg}{2}$ which will produce an acceleration of $\frac{g}{2}$ in the first ball of our system which corresponds to the first ball of the system given in the question and as a matter of fact, the first ball of the system given to us in the question will also move with an acceleration go $\frac{g}{2}$ !

Comment: You start by assuming that the tension in string $a$ is $mg$ (in which case the acceleration of mass #1 is $0$) and use this to deduce that the tension in string $a$ will actually be $\frac{mg}{2}$ (hence the acceleration of mass #1 will be $\frac{g}{2}$). So which result is correct? Is the acceleration of mass #1 $0$ or is it $\frac{g}{2}$? ... If your assumption leads to a contradiction, the logical consequence is that the assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @sammygerbil , first of all we are given an infinite set of pulleys and if we call this infinite set of pulleys $A$ . If I put tension in $a = mg$ then the system which we choose will behave exactly the same as $A$ because in both of the systems ( the one we made and the one given to us in the question ) the first pulley is stationary and there are infinite pulleys.

Comment: Because of this the tension in $b$ will be $\frac{mg}{2}$ and that would mean that the second ball of $A$ has an acceleration of $\frac{g}{2}$ which should behave exactly as the first ball of $A$. So the first ball of $A$ has zero acceleration and the second ball of $A$ has  an acceleration of $\frac{g}{2}$. There ain’t any contradictions!

Comment: What do you mean? The top ball will accelerate upwards.

Comment: Ok, The tension, acting upwards is mg/2 and the force acting downwards is mg, so net acceleration is downwards at g/2. That is unless maybe you're talking about relative acceleration?

Comment: Aha. I didn’t notice that. That simply means that the 1st pulley must go down with g/2